# Shell script avoiding that 2 options can be used at the same time

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script

it works great, the only problem I have is that I want to avoid the possibility of using both options -d) and -x) at the same time when executing my command with my parameters in directories.
Could this be possible with a minimal change in my code?

```
#!/bin/bash

   dir=$1

if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then
   echo "ERROR: no argument"
   exit 1 # pas 0
else
    case $2
in
    -d)
       mv $dir/ /tmp/
       echo 'moving with -d'
       ;;
    -x)
       for f in "$dir"/*; do [[ -x $f ]] && mv "$f" /tmp; done
       echo 'moving executables'
       ;;
    *)
       mv $dir/* /tmp/
       echo 'no flag passed so moving all'
       echo "mv $dir/* /tmp/"
       ;;
     esac
 fi
```

Comment: Read up on getopts for processing arguments: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the other way: first extract options, then "if" it.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$1

shift

while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    case $1
    in
    -d)
       D_OPTION_SELECTED=1
       ;;
    -x)
       X_OPTION_SELECTED=1
       ;;
     esac
    shift
done

help() {
 echo "Usage $0 dir [-x or -d]";
}

if [[ "$dir" == "" ]]; then help; exit 1; fi
if [[ $D_OPTION_SELECTED -gt 0 && $X_OPTION_SELECTED -gt 0 ]]; then help; exit 1; fi

if [[ $D_OPTION_SELECTED -gt 0 ]]; then echo D selected; fi
if [[ $X_OPTION_SELECTED -gt 0 ]]; then echo X selected; fi
```

But please remember that the good rule is to allow options at first places. So the better version would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    case $1
    in
    -d)
       D_OPTION_SELECTED=1
       ;;
    -x)
       X_OPTION_SELECTED=1
       ;;
    *)
       dir=$1
       ;;
     esac
    shift
done

help() {
 echo "Usage $0 [-x or -d] dir";
}

if [[ "$dir" == "" ]]; then help; exit 1; fi
if [[ $D_OPTION_SELECTED -gt 0 && $X_OPTION_SELECTED -gt 0 ]]; then help; exit 1; fi

if [[ $D_OPTION_SELECTED -gt 0 ]]; then echo D selected; fi
if [[ $X_OPTION_SELECTED -gt 0 ]]; then echo X selected; fi
echo dir=$dir
```